# Google Merchant feed double encoded UTF-8 error

Tags: encoding, utf-8, rss2

I got error from Google Merchant Center on data feed which says:

> Double encoded UTF8 in attribute "title"

However there are 1914 items in feed and this error occurs only on 58 items, so I guess the encoding of whole feed is correct, but there must be some wrong character, but I am unable to recognize it. Wrong titles (Czech language):

- Plášť Specialized Fast Trak Sport Tire 650Bx2.0
- Plášť Specialized Ground Control 2Br Tire 650Bx2.3
- Plášť Specialized Fast Trak Sport Tire 29X2.0
- Plášť Specialized Roller Tire 16X2.125
- Plášť Specialized Fatboy Tire 29X1.7 / 700X45C

When I show source code of feed, everything seems fine:

```
<title>Plášť Specialized Fast Trak Sport Tire 650Bx2.0</title>
```

Other titles like this one are correctly imported:

```
<title>Plášť Turbo Elite Tire 700X23C</title>
```

I don't know what is wrong in those titles, maybe the part 650Bx2 etc. is interpreted by Google as some kind of UTF-8 character?

Answer (score 1):

What helped me with diacritics in google merchant was to html encode multi-byte characters. In you case it would be to replace `ť` with `&#x165;` so instead of having:

```
<title>Plášť Specialized Fast Trak Sport Tire 650Bx2.0</title>
```

you would have:

```
<title>Pl&#xE1;&#x161;&#x165; Specialized Fast Trak Sport Tire 650Bx2.0</title>
```

I am not sure why it works in some cases without escaping and in some it doesn't. Escaped content works for me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - problem is with char "ť" (t with diacritic caron), I replace all occurrences of this char with char "t" and XML feed was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use utf-16.
I get some error with sumbol ® and problem solved only by changinf xml file encoding.